# Can we add two if statements side by side?

Tags: inequality, logic, foundations

Let we have following two if statements:

\begin{eqnarray*}
a &\leqslant &b\Rightarrow x\leqslant y \\
c &\leqslant &d\Rightarrow z\leqslant t
\end{eqnarray*}
Do the following inequality is correct ?
\begin{equation*}
a+c\leqslant b+d\Rightarrow x+z\leqslant y+t
\end{equation*}
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I looks very false. Let us take real numbers. It is true that
$a\le b \Rightarrow a\le b$ and that $c\le d \Rightarrow c/2 \le d/2$ but I don't think that
\begin{equation}
a + c \le b + d \Rightarrow a + c/2 \le b + d/2
\end{equation}
for example $3 + 2\le 2 + 3$ but $4 = 3 + 2/2 > 2 + 3/2 = 3.5$

Comment: It didn't occur to me to give a counterexample. I thought very complex. Many thanks for your nice answer.